# PHP Mysql Paginating results

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Hey I am trying to have paginated results for a book store but I can not figure out why my links to other pages will not work. When I run this the original page loads the results but when I go to the next page it says items not found.

```
<?php
$host = '???'; //IP Address on domain name of the host for the database
$user ='???'; //the name of the user
$pass="???";//Our Password

//make the connection to the database
$con=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or
die("Error connecting to Database");

$dbname = "???"; //we had a database name ???
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>





<?php
echo "<br><h3><u>Available Books for Sell</u></h3><br>"; // promps user to order a book
$per_page=5;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {

$page = $_GET["page"];
}
else {
$page=1;
}

// Page will start from 0 and Multiple by Per Page
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

$query="select * from Books limit $start_from,$per_page"; // create query using the $_GET 'id' sent
$result=mysql_query($query); //results from executing the mysql query
    if(!$result) // if not results
    {
    echo" get Items error"; // print error
    exit;
    }
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) // while there are results
    {
    echo 
    "<br>----------------------------------------------------------------------
    <br>Title:  ".$row['Title'].
    "<br>Author: ".$row['Author']. //print row price, name, author
    "<br>ISBN: ".$row['ISBN'].
    "<br>Condition: ".$row['BookCondition'].
    "<br>Price: ".$row['Price'].
    "<br>Sellers Username: ".$row['Uname'];
    echo"<br>";
    echo"----------------------------------------------------------------------";
    }


//Now select all from table
$query = "select * from Books";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Count the total records
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);

//Using ceil function to divide the total records on per page
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

//Going to first page
echo "<center><a href='getItems.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a> ";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {

echo "<a href='getItems.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
};
// Going to last page
echo "<a href='getItems.php?page=$total_pages'>".'Last Page'."</a></center> ";
?>
```

Comment: stop using `mysql` its depreciated

Comment: try to echo ur query and check what page values u get.

Answer (score 0):

> this may help you

```
<?php
             $dbhost = 'localhost';
             $dbuser = '---';
             $dbpass = '---';

             $rec_limit = 1;
             $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

             if(! $conn )
             {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
             }
             mysql_select_db('---');

             /* Get total number of records */
             $sql = "SELECT count(user_id) FROM table_name";
             $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

             if(! $retval )
             {
                die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
             }
             $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
             $rec_count = $row[0];

             if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
             {
                $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
                $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
             }
             else
             {
                $page = 0;
                $offset = 0;
             }
             $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
             $sql = "SELECT company_name, e_mail, international_code, mob_number, nationality, current_loc, pref_location, 
             key_skills, address, user_dob, training, lang1, lang2, lang3, lang4 ".
                "FROM se_job_contracts ".
                "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

             $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

             if(! $retval )
             {
                die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
             }

             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
             {
                echo "<b>Company Name</b> :{$row['company_name']}  <br> ".
                   "<b>Email-ID</b> : {$row['e_mail']} <br> ".
                   "<b>International code </b> : {$row['international_code']}  "."    <b>Mobile No </b> : {$row['mob_number']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Nationality </b> : {$row['nationality']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Current Location </b> : {$row['current_loc']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Preferred Location </b> : {$row['pref_location']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Key Skills </b> : {$row['key_skills']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Address </b> : {$row['address']} <br> ".
                   "<b>User DOB </b> : {$row['user_dob']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Training  </b> : {$row['training']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Language known 1 </b> : {$row['lang1']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Language known 2 </b> : {$row['lang2']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Language known 3 </b> : {$row['lang3']} <br> ".
                   "<b>Language known 4  </b> : {$row['lang4']} <br> ".
                   "--------------------------------<br>";
             }

             if( $page > 0 )
             {
                $last = $page - 2;
                echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Previous </a> |";
                echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next >></a>";
             }

             else if( $page == 0 )
             {
                echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next >></a>";
                }

             else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
             {
                $last = $page - 2;
                echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Previous </a>";
             }

            mysql_close($conn);
          ?>
```

Comment: While that might be the solution to the issue, care to explain abit what was changed? And why you changed exactly that? This is just a code-dump, not really a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).